# How can I transfer a value from one Go channel to another without an implicit buffer?

Tags: go, pipeline, channel

Imagine I have a goroutine that reads from one channel and writes to another.

```
ch1 := make(chan int)
ch2 := make(chan int)
go func() {
  for num := range ch1 {
    ch2 <- num+1
  }
}()
```

If `ch2` is blocked, the goroutine will still read a value from `ch1`, effectively introducing a buffer of 1 in the channel. Since I'm using channels for control flow I don't want any buffering.

How can I make a pipeline that executes in a completely lock-step fashion?
Or put differently, how can I transfer a value from one channel to the next in one atomic operation?

I basically want to wait for both `ch1` and `ch2` to be at a rendezvous point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with 2 channels. In order to perform a send on `ch2`, the value to be sent must already be ready, evaluated. [Spec: Send statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)

> Both the channel and the value expression are evaluated before communication begins.

So even if you would do this, which seemingly does not buffer the value in any variable:

```
ch2 <- (<- ch1)
```

Still, the receive from `ch1` would be evaluated first, and only then would the send be attempted.

Which means that value must have already  been received from `ch1`. But you can't tell if anyone is "listening" on `ch2` (meaning if a send on `ch2` could proceed) without attempting to send on `ch2` (and even if you could, there is no guarantee that attempting a send after a check there would still be someone listening on it).

Comment: Just as a note: Rob Pike [proposed](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26282) to add a `splice` to channel in Go 2 which seems to be just for this problem.

Comment: The original splice proposal does not really cover what I want, but https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26282#issuecomment-405786296 this is exactly what I described above. Except I'm not sure what he means by how to refactor that code.